# How can I suppress the Just My Code dialog when using emitted IL code?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, exception, reflection.emit

I have emitted some IL code that invokes user code.  I wrap the invocation of my IL code (from user code) in a try/catch block to catch any Exceptions that happen inside of it.  The inner user code throws an Exception which is caught properly by the outer user code's try/catch block.  This is all as desired.

However, when I turn Just My Code on, the debugger breaks where my inner user code first throws the Exception.  This is undesirable behavior -- the inner code is wrapped in a try/catch (through the emitted IL), so it is handled and I don't want the Exception dialog to pop up.

I suspect the dialog is popping up because the Exception is passing from user code (the InternalMethod) to "non-user code" (the emitted IL) since the emitted IL shows as "[External code]" in the call stack.  Is it possible to mark the emitted IL code as user code so that the Exception passes through without causing Just My Code to display the Exception dialog?

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Threading;

namespace ExceptionInEmitDemo
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var internalMethod = typeof(Program).GetMethod("InternalMethod", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

            var assembly = Thread.GetDomain().DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("DynamicAssembly"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
            var moduleBuilder = assembly.DefineDynamicModule("DynamicModule", false);
            var typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType("DynamicType");
            var methodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("DynamicMethod", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static, typeof(void), new Type[] { });
            var ilGen = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();
            ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, internalMethod);
            ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
            var dynamicType = typeBuilder.CreateType();

            MethodInfo dynamicMethod = dynamicType.GetMethod("DynamicMethod");
            try
            {
                dynamicMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { });
            }
            catch (TargetInvocationException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Caught Exception: " + ex.InnerException);
            }
        }

        public static void InternalMethod()
        {
            throw new Exception("This Exception will be caught in the try/catch block");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem could be that there is more external code involved, the `MethodInfo.Invoke()` methods code.

You could either add a `DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute` to the invoked method, but that is most likely not viable.

Or you could create a delegate to the target method.

```
try
{
    var d = (Action)dynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action));
    d();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Caught Exception: " + ex);
}
```